# Save app to desktop Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I would like to know how can I save a desktop application into a desktop as I can launch it in the future directly on **THIS** virtual desktop whatever where I am ?

#### For example :

If I start firefox on Desktop(D) #2, i would like the next time FF launches on D2, whatever if I'm on D1,D3,D4 etc..

Comment: Universal Application or a Desktop application.  You create a shortcut to your desktop applications exactly how you have been creating them for the last 2 decades.

Comment: Desktop App, i think i'm not very clear. If I start firefox on D2, i would like the next time FF launches on D2, whatever if I'm on D1,D3,D4 etc..

Comment: Virtual Desktops don't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout VDesktop for W10 -- [GitHub](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) | [GHacks Review](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/06/15/vdesk-virtual-desktops-windows-10/)

> VDesk is a free, open source, program for the Windows 10 operating
> system that extends a system's virtual desktop functionality.

Example usage:

```
vdesk create
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:"D:\myFolder\myProg.exe"
```